# Basis for range and kernel of T and prove rank nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$$
     T   \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 +3x_2\\
        x_2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

By considering $ker(T)$ first
$$ker(T)=\{(x_1,x_2) |T(x_1,x_2)=0\}  \\
x_1+3x_2=0 \implies x_1=-3x_2  \\
ker(T)=(-3x_2,x_2)=x_2(-3,1)   \\
\therefore basis(ker(T))=\{(-3,1)\} $$

and by considering $$im(T)=\{(x_1+3x_2),(x_2)\} = \{x_1(1,0)+x_2(3,1)\}  \\
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        3 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

can be reduced to 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ So$$basis(im(T))=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$$

Is the above correct?

But when considering the rank nullity theorem :-
$$dim(im(T)) +dim(ker(T)) = dim(v)=3$$ but it's not is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ker(T) =(0,0)$

As $T(x_1,x_2)=0 \Rightarrow x_1+3x_2=0$ **and** $x_2=0$

And so the rank nullity theorem still holds.

Comment: So $dim(ker(T))=0 $ or $1$ ?

Comment: dim(ker(T)) =0 . As by convention dimension of zero vector is zero.